# why the endian of write Struct in file is different with the Struct in memory?

Tags: c

I try to write a struct into file, then i found the endian of that is differet with the endian in the memory.

some test code:

```
void show_hex(unsigned char *p, int n)
{

    for (int i=0; i<n;i++){
        printf("%02X ",p[i]);
    }

}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("as","w");
    struct X{
        int x,y;
    };
    struct X *p = malloc( sizeof(struct X));
    p->x = 0xFFEECCAA;
    p->y = 0xFFAADD;
    show_hex((unsigned char *) p, sizeof(struct X));
    fwrite(p, sizeof(struct X), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    int f = open("as2",O_WRONLY);
    write(f, p, sizeof(struct X));
    close(f);
    return 0;
}
```

the problem out put  :  AA CC EE FF DD AA FF 00   //i know that is the little endian

```
tyw@um08:~/pro|master⚡ ⇒  hexdump as
0000000 ccaa ffee aadd 00ff                    
0000008
tyw@um08:~/pro|master⚡ ⇒  hexdump as2
0000000 ccaa ffee aadd 00ff                    
0000008
```

So the endin is different.

Comment: You could have tested this by using `echo 1234 | hexdump` instead of assuming the endian was wrong.  When all else fails, `man hexdump`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The endianness of the file isn't different than the memory.  The default behavior of `hexdump` is to print the values as 16-bit shorts.  What you are seeing is a different interpretation of the memory.  Try `hexdump -C`